# Wordpress wp_query add custom query as field

Tags: wp-query

I want to add a custom query as field to my global $w_query. I explain: I use a custom query to calculate rating_score :

```
(
SELECT 
    AVG(M.meta_value) as rate_point

from 
    wp_posts as p 
    join wp_postmeta as M on M.post_id = p.ID 
Where 
        p.post_author = 44  
    and p.post_status ='complete' 
    and p.post_type = 'bid' 
    and M.meta_key = 'rating_score') as rating_score
```

I want to add this custom query as field to my global $wp_query.

Comment: You wanna filter the posts by `meta_key` or you just wanna get that `meta_key` inside main query ?

Comment: No I want to ORDER BY the result of the sub query.